# What does "Easy does it" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

It's here in this old radio play:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tOr3VaEqoDI&feature=share&list=UUJJ-L-Gxh432qktFvkFV6VA

at **1:53**

The man says: **"Easy does it."**

What does that mean?

Comment: A [google search for "easy does it meaning"](https://www.google.com/#psj=1&q=%22easy+does+it%22+meaning) seems to answer your question quite easily. (The first link that pops up is to [The Free Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Easy+does+it).) If you're still confused, feel free to edit to add what confuses you and I'd be happy to reopen the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is an idiomatic expression that means "slow down"; the man is saying to use a more "easy" effort. The expression is used when someone is doing something too quickly and might make a mistake because of speed, such as when moving heavy objects or cutting something. (Literally, an easy effort will do the job, but a hasty one might cause a problem.)

Comment: it can also mean, more generally, "relax"